# ios change App Controller delegate

Tags: ios, delegates

I need to catch the opening of links in ios application (for the Facebook login).
To do this, I simply define an interface method:

```
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application handleOpenURL: (NSURL *) URL
```

and for new versions of the system

```
- (BOOL) application: (UIApplication *) application
             openURL: (NSURL *) url
   sourceApplication: (NSString *) sourceApplication
          annotation: (id) annotation
```

Everything works, but I need to decouple the code from the AppController code file.
For this, I created a class that inherits all interfaces of AppController, and replace AppController delegate on my object:

```
@implementation ApplicationProxy

id <UIApplicationDelegate> origin;
...
+ (void) changeDelegate{
   ApplicationProxy* proxy = [[ApplicationProxy alloc] init];
   origin = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setDelegate: proxy];
}
...
// replace all the functions of origin to work properly, such as
- (Void) applicationDidBecomeActive: (UIApplication *) application {
   [origin applicationDidBecomeActive: application];
}
...
@end
```

Everything worked fine in the project on ios 5 but with an update on the 6 version(and 4.5 version of XCode) of the iOs beginning of the crash.
Where is the confusion?

Comment: Could you please post your crash log and say where the crash is happening ?

Comment: Why oh why would you need to do anything like this? You should only have 1 delegate of UIApplication, ever. Don't do something like this, seriously.

Comment: @Cal In the log does not show anything, gives assembler-like code,`libobjc.A.dylib objc_msgSend:
0x311345a0:  teq.w  r0, #0
0x311345a4:  beq    0x311345e6                ; objc_msgSend + 70
0x311345a6:  push.w {r3, r4}
0x311345aa:  ldr    r4, [r0]
0x311345ac:  lsr.w  r9, r1, #2
0x311345b0:  ldr    r3, [r4, #8] //EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1,adress=0x8)
0x311345b2:  add.w  r3, r3, #8
0x311345b6:  ldr    r12, [r3, #-8]
0x311345ba:  and.w  r9, r9, r12
`@mattjgalloway Yes, I know it's a 100% trick.
I did so only to separate the module code from the MainActivity.